# Mysql For Excel: No Connection Showing

Tags: mysql, excel, for-loop

I am having an issue for Mysql for Excel plugin, when I first installed it, it was showing my local connections, etc. I shut the programs and re-opened it and it has refused to show anything since then, it does not show local connection or remote connection - but everything is working well from MYSQL Benchmark, I can see all the connections, etc, but the plugin in excel is just blank grey screen - as shown in the screenshot, I have uninstalled and reinstalled both my excel and the plugin, still giving the same error, any ideas or help will be appreciated

[image: Excel Screen]

Answer (score 4):

Working solution from https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96047

> Simply start up Excel, click on File at the top left, click on Options
>   at the bottom left, select General in the Excel Options dialog and
>   under User Interface Options select Optimize for Compatibility, click
>   OK and restart Excel.  Your connections should now appear.

Answer (score 2):

**Eureka Eureka**  I found it

The same thing has happened to me. It was working and then the next time no connections.  I have spent hours and days and weeks trying to get it to work again. After weeks of trying, I found the solution.

Apparently, Microsoft did a security upgrade to Excel.
Solution:

1. File
2. Options
3. Trust Center
4. Trust Center Settings....
5. Uncheck Enable Protected View for files originating from the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

apparently all of Mysql bugs relating to this say that you can fix this by updating Microsoft Office. Go to File > Account > Update Now

I hope that helps

Comment: [https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92320]        
[https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91050]  [https://support.office.com/en-us/article/install-office-updates-2ab296f3-7f03-43a2-8e50-46de917611c5]